# Does rust have support for embedded PowerPC targets?

Tags: rust, embedded, powerpc

I've so far only seen PowerPC in the target lists in the rustc book for operating systems such as Linux, but not for embedded.

From the LLVM docs, it implies they support embedded PowerPC, so in theory, Rust should be able to compile with a custom target right?

One problem I have seen though is it doesn't seem LLVM supports VLE, which means programs may be significantly larger in flash.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, there is a crate with [Platform-specific intrinsics for the PowerPC platform](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/powerpc/index.html)

I'm also interested in figuring out embedded Rust support for PowerPC e200, specifically, the ST SPC58NE84E7